# Multiple templates in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I'm pretty new to Gatsby and want to have multiple templates that i can use for my different pages, eg Landingpage, Contact and About cant have the same templates.

I have made a ugly code in gatsby-node.js for now but it only works for two templates, here is my code (btw I'm sourcing data from markdownfiles):

Mardownfile 1:

```
---
title: 'Index page'
slug: '/'
template: indexTemplate //This is where i declare which template it shall use
content: 'Index content'
---
```

Mardownfile 2:

```
---
slug: '/my-first-post'
date: '2019-05-04'
title: 'My first blog post!'
content: 'Content post 1'
template: postTemplate
---
```

gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
  
    const result = await graphql(`
    query{
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const postTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/postTemplate.js`)
  const indexTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/indexTemplate.js`)
  const aboutTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/aboutTemplate.js`) // I also want a template for my aboutpage
  
    // Handle errors
    if (result.errors) {
      reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
      return
    }

    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach( post => {
      createPage({
        path: post.frontmatter.slug,
        component: post.frontmatter.template === 'indexTemplate' ? indexTemplate : postTemplate, // Here is where the ugly "magic" happens...
        context: {
          slug: post.frontmatter.slug,
        },
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea of using `gatsby-node.js` is to create dynamic pages from some data source (CMS, markdown files, JSON files, external APIs, etc) with the [`createPage` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#createPages). In other words, it's really useful to create dynamic pages that have an unknown slug or name from a data source. The idea is to query all types of data (posts for instance) and pass via context some unique information (normally the `slug` or the `id`) as a filter parameter to perform another query in your template.

In your case, that fits for your blog (markdown file 2), but not for other known pages such as index, about, etc (markdown file 1). They are defined and known pages and should be treated differently, using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/). They are not templates because are unique pages, you won't have two different homes that can reuse a home template.

To identify different markdown pages, between posts and home page, for example, you can use a `key` value to filter your queries.

```
---
title: 'Index page'
slug: '/'
key: 'home'
template: indexTemplate //This is where i declare which component it shall use
content: 'Index content'
---
Content of the index page.
```

And:

```
---
slug: '/my-first-post'
date: '2019-05-04'
key: 'post'
title: 'My first blog post!'
content: 'Content post 1'
template: postTemplate
---
```

When creating a pages dyamically (via `gatsby-node.js`) the approach should look like:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "article" }}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note the filter for the `key` value.*

Then, in your `blog-post` (template):

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function BlogPost({ data }) {
  const post = data.markdownRemark
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

For your static pages, just make the query on the page. For your `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <div>
     Your page title is {data.nodes[0].frontmatter.title}
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "home" }}}) {
       nodes{
         frontmatter{
           title
         }
       }
    }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

Feel free to adapt the code to your needs. The important thing is that you should differentiate between what should be used as a template (blog, posts, articles, or other dynamic data) and what should be handled statically (home, about, or other static pages).

---

Of course, upon the scope of the question, you can have multiple templates, let's say one for posts and the other for reviews (or other dynamic data). You can simply achieve it by saving your query result inside a variable and call twice the `createPage` API:

```
const result1 = await graphql(`
    query{
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

const result2 = await graphql(`
    query{
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const postTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/postTemplate.js`)
  const reviewsTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/reviewsTemplate.js`)
    // Handle errors
    if (result1.errors || result2.errors) {
      reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
      return
    }

    result1.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach( post => {
      createPage({
        path: post.frontmatter.slug,
        component: postTemplate
        context: {
          slug: post.frontmatter.slug,
        },
      })
    })

    result2.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach( review => {
      createPage({
        path: review.frontmatter.slug,
        component: reviewsTemplate
        context: {
          slug: review.frontmatter.slug,
        },
      })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I will check it out more properly when i get home. 

I got one more question, have you tried doing like this?:



result.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach( post => {
      createPage({
        path: post.frontmatter.slug,
        comoponent: path.resolve(`./src/templates/${post.frontmatter.template}.js`),
        context: {
          slug: post.frontmatter.slug,
        },
      })
    }

Comment: Then you dont need to change the gatsby-node.js every time you add a page?

Comment: The idea is to work towards the optimization of the code. If your markdown has the information of the component, you can use the same loop through all kinds of pages, being the component who chose which one should render. However, that's low scalable, since it will force you to change all the page creation if your data structure changes. In addition, it's less readable. Of course, the project and the choice are yours. What's important to keep is that the home page is not a template., it's a waste of node cycles to use it like a template.

Comment: `result1` and `result2` in the last example seem to hold the same data. Why not foreach on `result1` twice instead of querying the same data twice?

Comment: Those variables are mocks to show how to retrieve different data from different nodes in a single instance of `createPages` since the question doesn't provide further details about the data structure. Of course, if the real use-case is to fetch the same data, you can omit one query.